# Excute a for loop after the completion of a previous loop

Tags: matlab, if-statement, for-loop, conditional-statements

I have written the following for loop;

```
%Name Variables
%Time Data Structure
Time_DataC1 = [];
for aa = 1:38
    for bb = 1:38
    fieldname = ['Time' num2str(aa)];
    Time_DataC1.(fieldname) = dataCOMB{1,1}{1,bb}(1:1024,1);
    end
end
```

which created a time data structure. Basically this code takes data from an array within an array and names the first column Time1, Time2 up to Time38 etc. It does this for the 38 data sets. However, once this is done, is it possible to change to code to

```
 Time_DataC1.(fieldname) = dataCOMB{1,cc}{1,bb}(1:1024,1);
```

where cc now goes from 1 to 2. Then the value bb starts from 1 and continues to 38 again. This would allow me to record the next time data set from Time39 to Time76. Once this is done can cc be changed to 3 and repeat the process until cc finally finishes at a value of 40?

I have tried using `if` and `elseif` statements but I keep getting errors.

Comment: It worked! :) Thanks :) Unbelievable how the simplest method is the one that works!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
for cc=1:2
    for aa=1:38
        for bb = 1:38
            fieldname = ['Time' num2str(aa + (cc-1)*38)];
```

That way, your field name uses the outer loop (`cc`) to count off how many times you have counted to `38` already.

Comment: I noticed an error. It names the files Time1 to Time 78 correctly but it collects the wrong data and I can't understand why. As you can see from above cc should stay at 1 and bb should start at 1 and move in increments of 1 until it reaches a value of 38. This will give me Time1-38. Then cc should change to 2 and remain at this value until bb has again incremented through 1 to 38 again. However, I am getting the problem where the first data is taken from U_Velocity.(fieldname) = dataCOMB{1,1}{1,38}(1:1024,2); where bb=38 instead of 1. any ideas on how to fix this??

Comment: I'm sorry. I can't quite follow your problem. When do you arrive at dataCOMB{1,1}{1,38}(1:1024,**2**);? In your question, you iterate through dataCOMB{1,**cc**}{1,**bb**}(1:1024,1); - which now makes me ask - what do you need the **aa** for? Other than the name? Or should that just be one loop instead of two?

Comment: I figured it out. It should only be for one loop instead of two so I just tweaked the code and it works now